# Firestore write to document invalid type errors for numpy

Tags: python, firebase, numpy, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dictionary with over 1000 fields that I'm trying to write to Firestore as a document. However, I keep getting invalid type errors like below:

```
'Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', 3, 'Invalid type', <class 'numpy.int64'>
'Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', False, 'Invalid type', <class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

Most of my fields are of these numpy types. I'm new to Firestore so I'm not sure if I missing something simple or If I have to convert all my fields? Does the Firestore python library not allow numpy types? I have multiple nested dictionaries within the main dictionary so it won't be easy to convert everything to different types.

Here is the python code I'm using to write to Firestore:

```
firestore_db.collection("collection_name").document("doc_name").set(allVarsDict)
```

Here is a sample of the dictionary:

```
{
'price_date': '2020-08-22 00:00:00',
'time_ms': 1598054400000,
'price1min': 11526.32,
'price_open1min': 11529.99,
'volume1min': 12.75662516,
'price': 11526.32,
'price1min_dict': {
    'price_date': '2020-08-22 00:00:00',
    'ms': 1598054400000,
    '50ma': 11525.190199999994,
    '128ma': 11547.188046874997,
    '200ma': 11569.5485,
    '200ema': 11552.031164880687,
    'heightPer': 0.0013139635732870457,
    'pinbarPer': 0.24224422442245286,
    'hammer': True,
    'star': False,
    'green': False,
    'pinbar': True,
    'height': True,
    'rsi': 49.58870472682622,
    'Mflow': -3.0986389827593954,
    'cmf': -0.39267912421581946,
    'obv': 12.09637204,
    'stoch': 85.27999999999884,
},
```

Comment: Is it possible to add sample how do you create such values?

Comment: I added the sample as requested. When I look in the debugger, vars like "height" and 'pinbar' are showing up as type 'bool_' instead of regular bool. Not sure why since I'm not including numpy in my script

Comment: There must be something else in your implementation. I have tried to replicate this in Python API and didn't get any errors. Value was inserted to Firestore properly. So how do you create this `allVarsDict` variable?

Comment: Thanks for trying @vitooh Did you have them as numpy types? I wound up having to convert all my numpy var types to standard python types, and it would save to firestore then. Would be less processing power and reduce error potential without the extra step though

Comment: This seems to be Feature Request. You can log it [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report).

Answer (score 2):

NumPy has a slightly different way to represent data. In other words, `numpy.int64` is not the same as `int` and is therefore not one of the [acceptable data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) in Firestore

There are many ways to overcome this problem. Depending on how you are obtaining the data, there could be a more efficient approach. However, with the information provided, this is the only way I could suggest which seems to work for me, which involves using [ndarray.item](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method:

```
def np_to_fs(og_dict):
    for k, v in og_dict.items():
        if type(v).__module__ == 'numpy':
            og_dict[k] = v.item()
```

This function would convert all instances of values of types originating from numpy and replace them with python-native variables.

Keep in mind that since you have nested dictionaries, you will have to call `np_to_fs` multiple times, once for each dictionary, and that the function will replace the values in-place.